# OpenShift New Installation

Tags: ansible, openshift, openshift-origin

I am new to OpenShift and ansible. I in the process of on a POC for an OpenShift installation.

1.What a typical installation of OpenShift in a POC environment looks like?  I was thinking one master, one infrastructure, and one application node.

2.How long does a normal installation take for first timers?

3.Where would the registry reside?

4.Will the route on the master?

Answer (score 1):

This may answer some of your questions. Maybe go though the actual install process yourself so you can see what is involved and how long it takes.

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/02/23/openshift-for-developers-set-up-a-full-cluster-in-under-30-minutes/

Specifically
1 - The pre-requisites will probably answer how many you will need as this can vary based on need. 
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/prerequisites.html
So 3-3-3 for redundancy, failover etc can be a good setup.

2 - It can really depend since there are many different variables like how many masters, how many nodes etc etc. In the video he does a simple installation with ansible in about 30 minutes.

3- For us our registry is running on our infrastructure nodes with storage to s3

4 - not sure I understand this one sorry.